# When I install win xp in a virtual machine in vmware it stops at "Windows XP setup - please wait" screen with 100% CPU use

Tags: windows-xp, installation, vmware

When I install win xp in a virtual machine in vmware it stops at "Windows XP setup - please wait" screen with 100% CPU use.

I've waited for more than 1 hour and nothing changes, what might be the problem?
thanks

Comment: You might want to share: 
- the version and software level of VMWare you're using
- your host operating system

Comment: it's a win xp pro with sp3. How do I know the vmware version? (I've downloaded 1 month ago from the official site)

Comment: For example, Player -> Help -> About gives me:

Product: VWware Player

Version: 5.0.1 build-894247

Comment: In addition to the VMWare info requested above, you should post your computer's BIOS info and host OS CPU speed and RAM. I've run into this on systems with limited BIOS capability, and on systems with limited CPU or RAM.